# In Eclipse debug mode, when I click "step into" it complains me "source not found"

Tags: eclipse, debugging, mode

In Eclipse debug mode, when I click "step into", it complains me "**source not found**".

> The JAR file `D:\Soft\apache-tomcate-7.0.00\lib\servlet-api.jar` has no source attachment.
>   You can attach the source by clicking Attach Source below.

Answer (score 0):

This means that you have the binary class file and it can't find source to show for the line that you're stepping into. You can solve it by attaching the source code, just as it says.

I think that servlet-api.jar works fine, and this is working correctly.